# Armijo backtracking with Jacobian Matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement an armijo backtracking algorithm for this function:
$$  f(x) = \frac{1}{2} ||Ax - b||_2^2, \hspace{10px} \nabla f(x) = A^T(Ax - b) \hspace{120px}b,x\in R^{m\times n}$$

But the condition in this case compares a scalar value with a matrix.
$$f(x_k+p_k)\le f(x_k)+c_1\alpha \nabla f(x_k)^T p_k\hspace{20px}p_k=-\nabla f(x_k)$$
How can I modify the armijo condition?

Comment: Where do you see a matrix in the condition? In the LHS you have the function value which is a scalar. In the RHS the first term is again a function value which is a scalar. The second term $\nabla f(x_k)^Tp^k$ equals $\|A^T(Ax-b)\|^2$, which is again a scalar

Comment: x and b are also matrix so we have $\nabla f(x_k)^T$ that is a matrix and also $p_k$ is a matrix.

Comment: I think you have a mistake. For the function dimensions to make sense, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^m$. You got a lot of things mixed-up there.

Comment: A is a blur matrix built by a PSF, it is a problem input I don't know how is made, the product of this matrix and x: $Ax \in R^{mn}$ . x and b are matrix that represents images. Sorry i was to generic in the description,